# convert color images to ttf font possible?

Tags: ios, image

Can I convert color images (PNG, JPEG) to TTF font (same appearance need)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a designer but I do have some experience with icon fonts. 

Our designer created an icon font for a project. He created the icons in black, we then set the correct icon color by the `.textColor` property on `UILabel`.

So I don't think its possible to have an icon font which supports multiple colours in the font, as you would overwrite it anyway.

We were using [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) to create the actual font. But you will need .svg files to create the font.